# How to type the return key by Ctrl+M (C-M) in the Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'd like to type a return/newline inside the shell by typing <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> because I'm familiar with Emacs and always type <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> to type return in Bash too.

However, inside the terminal of Google Cloud Shell, <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> does not send `^m` and just toggle the "Capture Tab Key" feature (see the screenshot below).

**off**
[image]

**on**
[image]

So the question is how can I type the return key by <kbd>Ctrl+M (C-M)</kbd>? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud SDK has the [gcloud cloud-shell ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/cloud-shell/ssh) command. This subcommand enables you to connect to your cloud-shell via ssh from your favorite terminal so that you can use `C-m` to type Return as always.

Though this solution cannot be used inside the Cloud Console, it seems the current best option for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think that  <kbd>\</kbd>  + <kbd>Enter</kbd> could help you.
For example:

[image]

In this way you can continue the command in the next row.

#### Edit 1

To send <kbd>ENTER</kbd> without using <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you could use

<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I didn't mean that. I'd like to send `Enter` without using `Enter` (Return key). (Sorry if my explanation was not clear.)

Comment: @shuuji3 I have added more information to my original answer. Please let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Jose. This method is not the best, but it solves my problem partly especially for the Bash shell. 

Comment: if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!